# Vertical list CSS with inline-block items

Tags: html, css, list

please help me to solve this issue.

I want that list on the red background to display in one row only.
I can't understand why the last item goes on a new line.

[image: Why does it display like this?]

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font: 14px/20px Arial, sans-serif; 
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
}
a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
header {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.90;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
p#logo {
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 350%;
}
nav {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D50000;
  float: right; 
}
nav ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <p id="logo">Lago Siu</p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu pranzo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu cena</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

I read other similar questions, but I can't solve the problem!

Comment: It looks like there is no enough horizontal space to display all items in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real pain that you are facing right now, is that you're using percentages for all of your widths.

This sounds like a good idea, but here's the issue:
the parent will figure out how wide its content is, and then set its width to match its children, the percentage of padding will then be the percentage of that width.  If the padding of the children is then percent-based (based on the different widths of each element), then you have shifting sizes, which means that the parent needs to readjust its width, recalculate, et cetera.

This doesn't work.
Moreover, you also run into rounding errors, where each browser rounds slightly differently. Percentages are great, until you have to figure out how many pixels that is.

And it's not even a question of the outermost boxes being a certain percentage; the 5% width of the parent's 10% width of the grandparent means that if the grandchild is rounded up a pixel, the parent is going to be rounded up a pixel, means the grandparent is going to be rounded up a pixel...

Unless the rounding goes the other way, in which case, your grandchild has less width, and/or your parent has less room to hold its children.

Instead of introducing yourself to that world of hurt, I'd suggest something like the following:

- use border-box on everything, all the time (use `*` instead of applying it individually)
- use margins very sparingly, and only for horizontal centering when there's nothing else that is going to appear on that line
- use `display: inline-block;` more often, and `text-align: center|left|right;` on the parent to control the flow of content
- use `em` and `rem` for padding, in sizes either relative to the font-size in the widget you're inside now (`em`) or relative to the default font-size (`rem`); instead of `font-size: 350%` you can use `font-size: 3.5rem;`
- try to use well-named classes (in a BEM or SuitCSS, or OOCSS style, if it helps) for your styling, and not rely on HTML selectors or IDs; I say this, because as your page complexity grows, the chances of two sets of `div div div span` colliding (and thus becoming a pain to style differently) become ***really high*** while the chances of `.MediaPlayer-button` colliding with `.CommentSection-submit` are still exactly 0, so long as the CSS selector isn't nested.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  font: 14px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* I've moved most of the commonly-repeating housekeeping CSS into utility classes */

.u-floatLeft {
  float: left;
}
.u-floatRight {
  float: right;
}
.u-noMargin {
  margin: 0;
}
.u-inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block;
}
.u-table {
  display: table;
}
.u-tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.u-fullHeight {
  height: 100%;
}
.Header {
  background-color: #333;
  /* by making the height REM-based, the header now updates in relative-size,
     as the base font-size changes, without needing to recalculate */
  height: 6rem;
}
.Logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  /* === 350%, but is more idiomatic, as its text-based */
  /* by making the line-height match the parent height,
     the logo-text will align itself properly */
  line-height: 6rem;
  /* I don't need any other margin or padding, now, except to move it right;
     use margin, instead, if the text needed its own background-color */
  padding-left: 0.75em;
}
.HeaderNav {
  background-color: #d50000;
}
.HeaderNav-list {
  /* <ul> and <ol> have a margin and a padding-left by default */
  /* 150% of an EM at this font-size and font-family */
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.HeaderNav-item {
  /* instead of % of total width, padding is now % of single EM */
  padding: 0 0.2em;
}
.HeaderNav-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.HeaderNav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.HeaderNav-link--current {}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="Header">
    <h1 class="Logo u-floatLeft u-noMargin u-fullHeight">Lago Siu</h1>
    <nav class="HeaderNav u-table u-floatRight u-fullHeight">
      <ul class="HeaderNav-list u-tableCell u-noMargin u-fullHeight">
        <li class="HeaderNav-item u-inlineBlock">
          <a href="#" class="HeaderNav-link HeaderNav-link--current">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="HeaderNav-item u-inlineBlock">
          <a href="#" class="HeaderNav-link">Menu pranzo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="HeaderNav-item u-inlineBlock">
          <a href="#" class="HeaderNav-link">Menu cena</a>
        </li>
        <li class="HeaderNav-item u-inlineBlock">
          <a href="#" class="HeaderNav-link">Info</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope that helps, both solve the problem, and give some basis for what's going on, in future issues you have, and how to tackle them.

Answer (score 0):

I basically just changed `<ul>` in the `<nav>` to `display: table` and then all inner `<li>`s to  `display: table-cell` with normal spaces replaced as unbreakable spaces `&nbsp;`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font: 14px/20px Arial, sans-serif; 
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
}
a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
header {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.90;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
p#logo {
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 350%;
}
nav {
  // display: table;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D50000;
  float: right; 
}
nav ul {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <p id="logo">Lago Siu</p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu&nbsp;pranzo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu&nbsp;cena</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically reduce the **padding** I have edited the CSS so 4 list items display in a horizontal line:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/arifbdev/73wpjz8v/]
```